# Scapy PcapReader and packets time

Tags: python, capture, pcap, packet-capture, scapy

I'm reading a PCAP file using Scapy using a script such as the (semplified) following one:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import *
# ...
myreader = PcapReader(myinputfile)
for p in myreader:
    pkt = p.payload
    print pkt.time
```

In this case the packets time is not relative to PCAP capture time, but starts from the instant I've launched my script.
I'd like to start from `0.0` or to be relative to the PCAP capture.

How can I fix it (possibly without "manually" retrieving the first packet time and repeatedly using math to fix the problem)?

Answer (score 6):

I saw that using `pkt.time` is wrong, in this case.
I should print `p.time` instead.